# How to dynamically recreate datagrid columns at runtime?

Tags: angular, vmware-clarity

I'm calling an API service that returns a JSON array. I also have a code in the front-end that composes a list of columns or fields based on the JSON. This list of columns is not a fixed-list and can be different based on the JSON content. So, I need to recreate the data grid columns dynamically at runtime.

It works when using *ngFor directive and loop through an array of columns that is pre-defined or pre-initialized in the code but, I need to change the list of columns at runtime.

Example:

```html
<clr-dg-column *ngFor="let field of fields" [clrDgField]="field.name">
    {{ field.text }}
</clr-dg-column>
```

```
let fields = [ { name: "id", text: "Id" }, { name: "name", text: "Name" }];

changeFields() {
    this.fields = [ { name: "userId", text: "User Id" }, { name: "desc", text: "Description" }];
}
```

When the `changeFields()` function is called, I expected the datagrid columns to be changed to the new list of columns. But the problem is that it doesn't re-render the columns.

The example below, shows the first image with the initial columns of the data grid, the 2nd image shows blank columns when changed at run-time

**Before changing the fields variables:**

[image: Before changing columns]

**After changing the fields at run-time:**

[image: After changing columns]

Comment: Do you have a simple reproduction of what you are doing exactly so we can more easily triage the request? We have starters at https://stackblitz.com/@clr-team

Comment: @JeremyWilken Sorry, I just incorrectly used the datagrid. It's now working perfectly. Here's what I'm currently working on. What I'm trying to achieve is to dynamically generate columns based on the keys of the first record in a JSON array. You can check this StackBlitz  if you're curious about it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v1-0-oadj7e